# Why does my breaker trip when turning on lights on another circuit?

Tags: circuit-breaker, afci

I'm trying to diagnose an issue that has cropped up in the last few days regarding a nuisance tripping breaker.

For background, I've lived in this apartment for 6 months now, with no notable changes to what's plugged in where that I can think of. This is a 2016 built building.

However, over the past three days I've had my breaker trip once every evening, usually when turning on a light switch on a completely different breaker. Here's a pic of the breaker. The [manual](http://apps.geindustrial.com/publibrary/checkout/DET-838?TNR=Brochures%7CDET-838%7CPDF&filename=DET-838B.pdf) I pulled up for this series of breakers suggests that an LED can indicate the last fault cause, but there's no illumination from the box, and instead I always get this orange trip flag:

[image: Breaker box with a gray 20A GE breaker in the tripped position, with an orange? trip flag]

Now, we have a couple of clues here. This appears to be an AFCI, or maybe DFCI, breaker. The fact that this is tripping when a light switch is flipped on another breaker makes me think the neutrals are connected to each other somewhere. There's a lot of interesting stuff on the circuit that trips, like a server rack with a UPS and some LED lights. However, none of the equipment there has changed recently, and if I pull my UPS logs, I'm drawing about 400W at full load, or about 3A. There's other things not going through the UPS, like some monitors and laptop chargers, but this is a 20A breaker and should have plenty of overhead to draw multiple times that and still sit under the 16A-at-load rule of thumb.

At first, I was content to blame the fact that I have an awful CFL + dimmer switch setup installed in the living room (not by my choice), and the fact I had been using the dimmer recently. My reading into AFCI suggests that CFLs, dimmers, and crossed neutrals can have an effect like this.

However, today the breaker was tripped with these lights on max, which is a condition I've had them in for the last several months.

I'm scratching my head at this one, and since we're in shelter-in-place out in California, I'm puzzling over the next steps before I call my landlord.

Some questions overall:
1. Any guesses about why this would happen when turning on lights in the other room, on a different circuit? Is my AFCI + combined neutrals theory correct?
2. Any guesses about why this would happen now, but wouldn't have for the last 6 months?
3. Is the breaker indicating any sort of information about the fault cause, or am I left guessing whether this is AFCI, GFCI, or overload caused?

Appreciate any suggestions you may have!

Comment: That's not a manual, that's a sales brochure.  [Try this](https://structuretech1.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/DET-719-CAFCI-Shared-Neutral-Guide.pdf). (what an interesting creature BTW).  *Well, we can cross off "shared/crossed neutral". This breaker **is designed** to thrive in  a shared neutral situation*.

Comment: Appreciate you digging that up. It doesn't give much info about the trip indicator, though. I'm not sure I understand the conclusion that it isn't a shared neutral. That linked manual says that MOD 3 is identified by having a gray case + black switch, and MOD 3 can be used on a shared neutral.

Comment: Yes, your breaker is a MOD 3 type -- it says so in the upside-down line of text that's currently at the top of the breaker case front

Comment: After reading the info from harpers link the neutral should not be the problem. You have a fair load for cfl/ LED of 4 amps . Having the dimmer on max really won’t help with most dimmers because although the dimmer is trying to output a true sine wave a harmonic is still generated at zero crossing if it is a Triac and if it is n SCR it turns off 1/2 cycle no matter what. Even without a dimmer I have seen AFCI’s have trouble with lights that use ballasts  (cfl, and LED lamps ) 4 amps is not a lot but on a circuit with electronics that would be enough when adding another lamp to cause the issue

Comment: Might be a loose connection inside the breaker box got worse and  some  neutral or ground line is not quite doing its job any more.

Comment: @EdBeal: I believe the theory that I have enough load on the circuit to cause an issue with the CFL + dimmer setup, but I will emphasize that the dimmer/CFLs are on a completely different circuit than the one that gets tripped (I can tell because they stay on, unlike my electronics). Does this still seem in line with your concerns?

Comment: I guess what I am thinking a neutral imbalance that would cause problems with GFCI’s can cause a problem with arc faults, the same electrical noise can cause problems on the line side and the breaker cannot tell where they are coming from and trip. The newer technologies in arc fault are supposed to be getting better but just prior to the lockdown for the virus I was asked to remove 3 breakers in a new home for this or a very similar reason , 2 being in bedrooms, it was the washing machine very repeatable a dedicated circuit with filters reduced the problem but I can’t remove the bedroom bkrs.